# JSP editor in Eclipse Mars

Tags: jsp, editor, eclipse-mars

I'm working with Eclipse Mars and Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools but there's no syntax highlight for jsp files. How to install a jsp editor?

Answer (score 3):

Help -> Install new software -> Work with : Mars - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars -> Web,XML, JavaEE and OSGi Enterprise Development -> enable `Eclipse Java EE Developer tools` -> Next and Finish.

You will then be asked to Restart Eclipse. After restarting, you'll get syntax highlight for jsp files.

**Thank you! :)**

Answer (score 1):

After installing the Eclipse java developer tools the jsp editor became available.